# How can I display "recent folders" in the sidebar of "Save as" dialogue?

Tags: 16.04, unity, nautilus

I was using 14.04 and upgraded to 16.04 yesterday.

In 14.04 I had recent folders on top of the sidebar of the *Save as* dialogue when I saved something from the net (Firefox if that helps). But that feature disappeared in 16.04 and I really want to have it back.

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to explain:
[image: the save window in 16.04 without the recent folder on top]
(the save as dialogue in 16.04 without the recent folders on top)

Comment: You're not. While 16.04 luckily got an older nautilus at the last minute, (3.14) it's using the newer (for that time) gtk3 which is what's handling/producing that dialog. What you see is what you get..

Answer (score 14):

This feature [has been removed by the developers](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=751653).

As a workaround you may press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> when the *Save as* dialogue pops up. This should list recent folders you have used to save files.

Comment: Thank you, I'd have preferred to have my recent folder back but it's a great workaround.

Comment: Thanks, I have been dealing with the same issue on Xubuntu. How can I switch back from `Alt+R`? More importantly, where can I find a list with these GTK3/GNOME key shortcuts?

Answer (score 6):

**A workaround** in addition to the answer of pomsky:

With a little hack, you actually can add "Recent" to your bookmarks. This way, "Recent" will be available in the "Save As" dialogue. Drawback of the hack is that "Recent" will appear twice in Files and in the GTK3 File Open dialog, once at the top above your special user folders, and once as a bookmark.

1. Open `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` in a text editor.
2. Add a new line (I suggest as the first line), containing `recent:///`
3. Save and close the file.

Next time when you start Files afresh, you will have a "Recent" bookmark, that also will show in the GTK3 file dialogs.

Comment: `recent:///` only shows recent files, not recent folders in for example the Thunar GTK3 file manager. Moreover, these files appear as locked.