# As a Xubuntu user, where can I find GTK3 FileChooserDialog shortcut key documentation?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, gtk3, documentation, dialog

Ever since browsers on Xubuntu started using GTK3 instead of GTK2, and when saving a file, I feel myself pretty lost in the FileChooserDialog.

By roaming the web, I found a few solutions to things that were self-evident in GTK2:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to [manually type a file location path](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-enter-file-location-manually-in-gtk-3-opensave-dialog/)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to [see recent folders](https://askubuntu.com/a/963049/164341), but I have no clue how to undo this view
- Entering a [new folder name is unreadable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/454177/39845), etc.

As a Xubuntu user, this move to GTK3 dialogs is quite abrupt, uninvited and more importantly not documented. Hence, my questions are very easy:

- Where can I find **a comprehensive list** of GTK3 FileChooserDialog magic keyboard shortcuts?
- Where can I find a list with the **CSS element IDs** of the GTK3 FileChooserDialog?

PS: I have been trying to hold this change at bay by installing GTK2 versions of applications wherever possible. However, a number of applications are no longer as GTK2 in the package manager.

Comment: Which version of Xubuntu are you using? What does `apt policy libgtk-3-0` show? Do you have the same experience with `mousepad` or some other gtk3 application? Are you using the default theme, Greybird, or something else?

Comment: @DKBose Here are the answers to your questions: Xubuntu LTS 16.04; `Installed 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3`; This happens with all GTK3 applications. I am using the default Greybird theme.