# Save file dialog does not show recently open files

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, gtk

Under ubuntu 18.04, when saving a file, the 'recent' folder is not present in the sidebar.
[Screenshot of the save file dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uu5Cg.png)

Meanwhile, when opening a file, the 'recent' folder is present.
[Screenshot of the open file dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxOIx.png)

This problem is annoying, because I often save files to a folder I have recently visited. Of course, I could use a bookmark, but most of time these folders are not for a longtime usage.

Is there a setting to enable a 'recent' folder in the save file dialog?

Comment: It's the normal behaviour of Nautilus. I don't see a way to change it.

Comment: Solved here: https://askubuntu.com/a/963049/50116  Press `ALT` + `R` in the dialog.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I display "recent folders" in the sidebar of "Save as" dialogue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963045/how-can-i-display-recent-folders-in-the-sidebar-of-save-as-dialogue)

Comment: Thanks! I will set my question as a duplicate.